# Plot two datasets on the same map with ggmap

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I have two datasets, drilling and earthquake namely. When I try and plot both separately on oklahoma map, it works fine. But I want to generate a map with both the data in it.
The code I used for mapping is:

```
Okla_sat_map <- get_map(location="Oklahoma", maptype="satellite", 
                        color="color", zoom=10)

ggmap(Okla_sat_map) + 
geom_point(aes(longitude, latitude, size=mag), colour="red", 
           data=earthquake.df, na.rm=T)
```

for drilling data:

```
Okla_sat_map <- get_map(location="Oklahoma", maptype="satellite", 
                        color="color", zoom=10)

ggmap(Okla_sat_map) + 
geom_point(aes(longitude, latitude, size=mag), colour="red", 
           data=drill.df, na.rm=T)
```

My data somewhat looks like this
Drilling data

```
    LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
1   36.85323    -98.38950
2   36.79886    -98.36245
3   36.66833    -98.26780
4   36.62468    -98.52917
5   36.53371    -98.10989
6   36.55837    -98.34455
7   36.55837    -98.34455
8   36.54467    -98.49612
9   36.51204    -98.16827
10  36.47222    -98.42875
11  36.61746    -98.51564
```

Earthquake data:

```
   longitude   latitude     mag
1   -97.4381    35.8336     3.0
2   -97.5731    36.1325     3.4
3   -99.0309    36.5110     3.1
4   -97.2297    35.8498     3.1
5   -97.5508    36.1254     3.0
6   -97.5460    36.2927     3.0
7   -97.8245    36.7062     3.0
8   -97.4250    35.8509     4.3
9   -97.4240    35.8219     3.1
10  -97.2674    36.2660     3.0
11  -97.0372    36.1966     3.1
```

Please help me plot both the data onto one map.

Comment: Drilling dataset as no information about magnitude.

Comment: Even if I add the third variable to drilling data, it still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you suggest me some way to plot it on one map?

Comment: Also, your points are outside the area delimited by the satellite map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a factorial variable column called e.g. 'type' to both data sets, set type in drilling to drilling, the type in earthquake as earthquake then merge the datasets by `rbind`.
Then plot as above with e..g `colour=type` to show the two sets by different colours.

Comment: I tried doing it, but it gives me this error "Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : invalid graphics state"

Comment: try running `dev.off()` to clear the device and then run script again clean from start